# SQL Connection Using Domain Username And Password

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I have developed an ASP.Net website. The problem I am facing is when I run the application in IIS on my system using the connection string in web.config ("Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=ITS;Integrated Security=True") it works well. I connects to the database and displays the data.

I have installed the database on a domain computer with the ASP.NET package in IIS. The problem here is it doesn't connects to the database. I have tried to use the connection string like this "Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=ITS;UID=S1\ISLWW74562S;PWD=delta$%67;Integrated Security=True"

Where S1 is the domain name and ISLWW74562S is the username.

It gives an error cannot find the login S1\ISLWW74562S$

Can anyone help me how and what is the proper way to use the connection string on a domain computer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the UID=S1\ISLWW74562S;PWD=delta$%67 from the connection string, and instead in IIS, create a special application pool for your web site and configure such application pool to run under the domain account.

Take a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx) to see how to setup the application pool to use a custom account.

Also, make sure that the domain account that you are using has the required access to the SQL database that you want to use.

If you are using Microsoft SQL server, then you need to use SQL management studio to create a new login for the domain user and give it the appropriate access to the database that you are using.

Comment: When ever I use the SQL Management Studio I have to run it as administrator . The administrator Username used there is ISLWW74562S\a154ey and the administrator Password is delta$%67. Then I am able to run the SQL server and view the tables and details in it. Should I use this administrator username and password in the connection string.

Comment: Putting the password in the connection string is a security issue. What I proposed is that you let the application pool that is used to run your web site in IIS run under an account that has database access (e.g. ISLWW74562S\a154ey).

Comment: The error is still there. It says "Login Failed For The User S1\ISLWW74562S$". Where S1 = Domain Name and ISLWW74562S$ = machine name. Even I have added a login for the database named S1\ISLWW74562S$ in the SQL Server, giving it the db_owner and sysadmin rights.

Comment: If you have anonymous authentication in IIS, then you might need to instruct IIS to use the application pool identity. See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for instructions to how make IIS use application pool identity when you use anonymous authentication.

Comment: Anonymous authentication is not allowed. I am using the forms authentication to login to the site. Even though I have given all the rights to the login S1\ISLWW74562S$ in the the SSMS . But still the login is failing for it.

Comment: What is the name of the application pool that your site is running under? Did you change the Identity of the application pool by going to the application pool -> Advanced Settings -> Identity -> Custom Account and then specify the domain account that has database access?

Comment: My site is running under the DefaultAppPool. Yes I did it. I have changed the identity to custom account and mentioned the username as S1\ISLWW74562S and password to delta$%67. Still it shows the error of login failed for user S1\ISLWW74562S$

Comment: Is S1\ISLWW74562S a domain user? What permissions did you give this account on the database in SQL Server?

Comment: S1 is the domain name and ISLWW74562S is the computer name.

Comment: I have found the issue. By changing the App Pool Identity to Local System its now connecting with the database.

Comment: Yacoub Massad . Thanks for all your . Really you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

When you use Integrated Security, you don't get to specify the username and password. Sql Server will not allow you to do this. Instead, it's looking for a token that was issued by the domain controller, and that's all it will accept.

You can get a token like this for your application by using the [Impersonation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc730708(v=WS.10).aspx) feature in IIS or by setting up the application pool for IIS to run as that user account.

Comment: The problem is if I have to any kind of changes in the system I have to do it by running the application in administrator mode. Even I have to run the IIS as administrator. How I would do that